# Can I access random data with random memory Addresses outside of my C++ Program

Tags: c++, pointers, ram, memory-address

If 2 programs are running, and one program stores a number at a memory address, and if I know that memory address, and hard code it into the 2nd program and print out the value at the address, would it actually get that info? Does C++ allow programs to access any data stored in RAM no matter if it is part of the program or not?

Comment: For Windows, you can use ReadProcessMemory(). But you don't mention the OS. Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: C++ doesn't stop you, but the *operating system* will most likely do that. Remember that modern multi-user operating systems separates process from each other, by many means. One of which is that process doesn't really have addresses in RAM, they have *virtual* addresses, and one virtual address in one process is not the same virtual address in another process. There may be OS-specific functions to access memory of other processes, but they are not part of C++, and their use often requires elevated privileges (or you would have enormous security holes).

Comment: This question has nothing to do with C/C++. To understand why, read up on virtual memory: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory

Comment: If you want to share memory between processes, you should probably be using just that, [shared memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_memory).

Comment: Even shared memory does not do what is being asked because (in most systems) shared memory can be mapped to different pages in the virtual address space.

Answer (score 8):

No, you'd get a `Segmentation Fault`

If I try to run this code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int *ptr = (int*) 0x1234;
    *ptr = 10;
}
```

I'd get a segmentation fault (unless 0x1234 has been allocated by the process for some reason), which is the operating system's way of telling you that you're not allowed to do that. Usually they'll happen when you're doing tricky things with pointers, but they can also happen elsewhere.

By default, they'll terminate your program immediately unless you're running in a debugger or have registered a signal handler to continue your program

Edit: If you really want, there's ways to get the operating system to let you do that, used by debuggers and such.

Answer (score 8):

On system with no virtual memory management and no address space protection this would work. It would be undefined behavior from the point of view of the C standard, but it would produce the behavior that you expect.

Bad news is that most computer systems in use these days have both virtual memory management and address space protection. What this means is that a memory address, the number that your program sees, is not unique in the system. Every process in the system may see the same address, but it would be mapped to a different physical address on your computer at any given moment in time. The operating system and the hardware will create illusion to each process that it has the control of that memory address, while in fact the memory spaces of the processes would not overlap.

Good news is that modern operating systems support some form of shared memory access, meaning that one process can share a segment of memory with other processes, and exchange data by reading and writing the data into that shared segment.

Comment: Wouldn't it be good news, that computer systems protect one program from accessing RAM from another program?

Comment: @PieterDeBie It's bad news only for the strategy described in the post. For every programmer it's great news (except hackers, they hate this).